# EA with OrderModify that modifys all open orders

Tags: mql4

EDIT:
This problem was caused by missing {}.
`if(OrderComment() == myTradeID)`and lots of code under neeth that line should be inside a {}

---

---

So I'm building an EA that reads from a file on the computer that has a string with information on what type of Order (NewOrder, AdjustOrder, or CancelOrder).

```
void AdjustTradeOrder(string myType,string mySymbole,string myTradeID,int myPosition,double myEntry,double myStopLoss,double myTakeProfit)
```

The problem I'm having is that inside the code below the EA sometimes just changes the right order but sometimes it changes all open orders and that's a big problem.

I'm trying to check if the myTradeID is the same as the comment on the selected order ID and only then should it modify the order. But sometimes it modifies all orders.

Any idea why?

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void AdjustTradeOrder(string myType,string mySymbole,string myTradeID,int myPosition,double 
myEntry,double myStopLoss,double myTakeProfit)
{

if(commentOnOpenOrders(myTradeID) && !commentOnOpenHistory(myTradeID))
 {
  //--- get minimum stop level
  double minstoplevel=MarketInfo(mySymbole,MODE_STOPLEVEL);
  double price=MarketInfo(mySymbole,MODE_ASK); ;
  double minilot = MarketInfo(mySymbole,MODE_MINLOT);

  color orderColor;
  if(myPosition==0)
    {
     orderColor = clrGreen;
    }
  else
    {
     orderColor = clrRed;
    }

  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  int PositionIndex;    //  <-- this variable is the index used for the loop
  int TotalNumberOfOrders;   //  <-- this variable will hold the number of orders currently in the Trade pool
  TotalNumberOfOrders = OrdersTotal();    // <-- we store the number of Orders in the variable

  for(PositionIndex = TotalNumberOfOrders - 1; PositionIndex >= 0 ; PositionIndex --)  //  <-- for loop to loop through all Orders . .   COUNT DOWN TO ZERO !
    {
     //Print("----------> AdjustTradeOrder       Part 3");
     if(! OrderSelect(PositionIndex, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES))
        continue;   // <-- if the OrderSelect fails advance the loop to the next PositionIndex
     if(OrderComment() == myTradeID)

        Print(myEntry + " ;" + myTakeProfit + " ;" + myTakeProfit);
     if(myEntry==0 && myTakeProfit==0 && myStopLoss>0)
        // MODIFT ONLY SL
       {
        Print("-----> ONLY SL");
        if(! OrderModify(OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), NormalizeDouble(myStopLoss,Digits),OrderTakeProfit(),0,orderColor))
           Print("[ONLY SL] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
        else
           Print("[ONLY SL] - OrderSend placed successfully");
        deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);

       }
     else
        if(myEntry>0 && myTakeProfit==0 && myStopLoss>0)
           // MODIFT ENTY & SL
          {
           Print("-----> MODIFT ENTY & SL");
           if(! OrderModify(OrderTicket(), NormalizeDouble(myEntry,Digits), NormalizeDouble(myStopLoss,Digits),OrderTakeProfit(),0,orderColor))
              Print("[MODIFT ENTY & SL] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
           else
              Print("[MODIFT ENTY & SL] - OrderSend placed successfully");
           deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
          }
        else
           if(myEntry>0 && myTakeProfit==0 && myStopLoss==0)
              // MODIFT ONLY ENTY
             {
              Print("-----> MODIFT ONLY ENTY");
              if(! OrderModify(OrderTicket(), NormalizeDouble(myEntry,Digits), OrderStopLoss(),OrderTakeProfit(),0,orderColor))
                 Print("[MODIFT ONLY ENTY] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
              else
                 Print("[MODIFT ONLY ENTY] - OrderSend placed successfully");
              deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
             }
           else
              if(myEntry>0 && myTakeProfit>0 && myStopLoss==0)
                 // MODIFT ENTY & TP
                {
                 Print("-----> MODIFT ENTY & TP");
                 if(! OrderModify(OrderTicket(), NormalizeDouble(myEntry,Digits), OrderStopLoss(),NormalizeDouble(myTakeProfit,Digits),0,orderColor))
                    Print("[MODIFT ENTY & TP] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
                 else
                    Print("[MODIFT ENTY & TP] - OrderSend placed successfully");
                 deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
                }
              else
                 if(myEntry==0 && myTakeProfit>0 && myStopLoss==0)
                    // MODIFT ONLY TP
                   {
                    Print("-----> ONLY Modify TAKEPROFIT");
                    if(! OrderModify(OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), OrderStopLoss(),NormalizeDouble(myTakeProfit,Digits),0,orderColor))
                       Print("[ONLY Modify TAKEPROFIT] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
                    else
                       Print("[ONLY Modify TAKEPROFIT] - OrderSend placed successfully");
                    deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
                   }
                 else
                    if(myEntry>0 && myTakeProfit>0 && myStopLoss>0)
                       // MODIFT ALL
                      {
                       Print("-----> MODIFT ALL");
                       if(! OrderModify(OrderTicket(), NormalizeDouble(myEntry,Digits), NormalizeDouble(myStopLoss,Digits),NormalizeDouble(myTakeProfit,Digits),0,orderColor))
                          Print("[MODIFT AL] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
                       else
                          Print("[MODIFT AL] - OrderSend placed successfully");
                       deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
                      }
     if(myEntry==0 && myTakeProfit>0 && myStopLoss>0)
        // MODIFT SL & TP
       {
        Print("-----> MODIFT SL & TP");
        if(! OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(), NormalizeDouble(myStopLoss,Digits),NormalizeDouble(myTakeProfit,Digits),0,orderColor))
           Print("[MODIFT SL & TP] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
        else
           Print("[MODIFT SL & TP] - OrderSend placed successfully");
        deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
       }
     else
       {
        Print("-----> Don't Know What whent wrong.");
        Print(
           "myType = "+myType   + ";"+
           "mySymbole = "+mySymbole   + ";"+
           "myTradeID = "+myTradeID   + ";"+
           "myPosition = "+IntegerToString(myPosition)   + ";"+
           "myEntry = "+DoubleToStr(myEntry)   + ";"+
           "myStopLoss = "+DoubleToStr(myStopLoss)   + ";"+
           "myTakeProfit = "+DoubleToStr(myTakeProfit)
        );
       }
    }
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 }
else
 {
  //Print("TradeID Already exists = "+myTradeID);
 }
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the `comment` parameter of `OrderSend()` to store any critical information. It if often overwritten or appended to by your broker and is therefore considered very unreliable.

The `magic number` parameter is specifically used for filtering trades, and this is what you should be using.

It is difficult to correct your code without having access to the full EA, but the following should help you along your way.

```
void AdjustTradeOrder(string myType,string mySymbole,int magicNumber,int myPosition,double myEntry,double myStopLoss,double myTakeProfit)
{
   //--- get minimum stop level
   double minstoplevel=MarketInfo(mySymbole,MODE_STOPLEVEL);
   double price=MarketInfo(mySymbole,MODE_ASK); ;
   double minilot = MarketInfo(mySymbole,MODE_MINLOT);

   color orderColor;
   if(myPosition==0) orderColor = clrGreen;
   else orderColor = clrRed;

   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
      //Print("----------> AdjustTradeOrder       Part 3");
      if(!OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) continue;   // <-- if the OrderSelect fails advance the loop to the next PositionIndex

      if(OrderSymbol()!=Symbol()) continue; // Not the correct order symbol
      if(OrderMagicNumber()!=magicNumber) continue; // Not the correct magic number

      Print(DoubleToStr(myEntry, Digits) + " ;" + DoubleToStr(myTakeProfit, Digits) + " ;" + DoubleToStr(myTakeProfit, Digits));
      if(myEntry==0 && myTakeProfit==0 && myStopLoss>0)
      {
         // MODIFT ONLY SL
         Print("-----> ONLY SL");
         if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), NormalizeDouble(myStopLoss,Digits),OrderTakeProfit(),0,orderColor)) Print("[ONLY SL] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
         else Print("[ONLY SL] - OrderSend placed successfully");
         deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
      }
      else 
      if(myEntry>0 && myTakeProfit==0 && myStopLoss>0)
      {
         // MODIFT ENTY & SL
         Print("-----> MODIFT ENTY & SL");
         if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(), NormalizeDouble(myEntry,Digits), NormalizeDouble(myStopLoss,Digits),OrderTakeProfit(),0,orderColor)) Print("[MODIFT ENTY & SL] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
         else Print("[MODIFT ENTY & SL] - OrderSend placed successfully");
         deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
      }
      else
      if(myEntry>0 && myTakeProfit==0 && myStopLoss==0)
      {
         // MODIFT ONLY ENTY
         Print("-----> MODIFT ONLY ENTY");
         if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(), NormalizeDouble(myEntry,Digits), OrderStopLoss(),OrderTakeProfit(),0,orderColor)) Print("[MODIFT ONLY ENTY] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
         else Print("[MODIFT ONLY ENTY] - OrderSend placed successfully");
         deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
      }
      else
      if(myEntry>0 && myTakeProfit>0 && myStopLoss==0)
      {
         // MODIFT ENTY & TP
         Print("-----> MODIFT ENTY & TP");
         if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(), NormalizeDouble(myEntry,Digits), OrderStopLoss(),NormalizeDouble(myTakeProfit,Digits),0,orderColor)) Print("[MODIFT ENTY & TP] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
         else Print("[MODIFT ENTY & TP] - OrderSend placed successfully");
         deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
      }
      else
      if(myEntry==0 && myTakeProfit>0 && myStopLoss==0)
      {
         // MODIFT ONLY TP
         Print("-----> ONLY Modify TAKEPROFIT");
         if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), OrderStopLoss(),NormalizeDouble(myTakeProfit,Digits),0,orderColor)) Print("[ONLY Modify TAKEPROFIT] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
         else Print("[ONLY Modify TAKEPROFIT] - OrderSend placed successfully");
         deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
      }
      else
      if(myEntry>0 && myTakeProfit>0 && myStopLoss>0)
      {
         // MODIFT ALL
         Print("-----> MODIFT ALL");
         if(! OrderModify(OrderTicket(), NormalizeDouble(myEntry,Digits), NormalizeDouble(myStopLoss,Digits),NormalizeDouble(myTakeProfit,Digits),0,orderColor)) Print("[MODIFT AL] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
         else Print("[MODIFT AL] - OrderSend placed successfully");
         deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
      }
      if(myEntry==0 && myTakeProfit>0 && myStopLoss>0)
      {
         // MODIFT SL & TP
         Print("-----> MODIFT SL & TP");
         if(! OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(), NormalizeDouble(myStopLoss,Digits),NormalizeDouble(myTakeProfit,Digits),0,orderColor)) Print("[MODIFT SL & TP] - Order OrderModify failed, order number: ", OrderTicket(), " Error: ", GetLastError());
         else Print("[MODIFT SL & TP] - OrderSend placed successfully");
         deleteFile_AdjustTrade(fileName_Adjusted);
      }
      else
      {
         Print("-----> Don't Know What whent wrong.");
         Print("myType = "+myType   + ";"+
               "mySymbole = "+mySymbole   + ";"+
               "myMagicNo = "+IntegerToString(magicNumber)   + ";"+
               "myPosition = "+IntegerToString(myPosition)   + ";"+
               "myEntry = "+DoubleToStr(myEntry)   + ";"+
               "myStopLoss = "+DoubleToStr(myStopLoss)   + ";"+
               "myTakeProfit = "+DoubleToStr(myTakeProfit));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: My problem is every trade made is made with the same robot and the same magic.
And I'm getting my signal thru an emal.

I get an email with looking like this.

May 28, 09:05 PM – EUR/GBP - SHORT Position - From 0.8655 - Adjusted - Stop from 0.8645 to 0.8605, Target: unch. (S/T) 
Trade ID: R'(IFR) IO2WPO0F9265

because it's an email service I'm having a VB script in outlook store the relative values of the email in 3 different files. OPEN / ADJUST & CLOSE.

Comment: My EA is then reading from those file and eather open adjust or close an order depending on the tradingID thats stored in the comment sektion.

I do know that thats not the best solution but as of now thats what I got.

Comment: I'll update the mail question with the full EA code.